# What are the available stylus pens for iPad?

Tags: ipad

Am looking for a good quality stylus primarily to be used for note-taking apps.

Comment: http://adonit.net/product/jot-pro/

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic for Ask Different unless they are specific questions asking for a very specific product.

Answer (score 2):

If you want cheap, there's a youtube video on making your own stylus from the thin metallic-coated wrapper from a powerbar.

I cleaned up and cut out a narrow strip of the stuff, looped it over the tip of a comfortable but dried-out rollerball pen, and it seemed to work as well as the expensive foam tip stylus for which I paid $15.

Added: Here's [the Walt MossPuppet video](http://mosspuppet.com/2010/09/20/video-how-to-make-an-ipad-stylus-with-a-protein-bar-wrapper/).

Comment: I like this idea. I'm loathed to pay 20$ for a stylus for a device that's designed expressly not to require one.

Answer (score 1):

I like and use the [BoxWave](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BUI76S) stylus.

Answer (score 0):

[wired.com](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/01/fingers-on-with-the-chunky-alupen-ipad-stylus/) reviewed the [Alupen](http://www.xtand.net/alupen.html) recently:

> The weight is good. An aluminum tube would be too light and cause cramp. Like a fountain pen, the Alupen presses itself down for you. At first look, the pen seems to be too short for comfort, like one of those free pencils at Ikea. In use, it is actually long enough (and I have big hands).
>
> In fact, the only fault I can find is that the metal pen gets icy cold when left on my desk. But then, my desk is marble, and my apartment has no heating, so it could be that.
>
> $20 may be too rich for some, although a good fountain pen is much more, and with a stylus you never need to buy any ink. Available now, in silver and a range of anodized candy-coatings.

Answer (score 0):

Griffin Technologies makes a pretty good [Stylus](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/stylus) as does TenOneDesign, the [Pogo Sketch](http://tenonedesign.com/sketch.php). I have the Griffin stylus and really like using it. The all metal, except for the tip, construction feels good to use and the clip holds the stylus nicely in a pocket or on a case. The Pogo Sketch runs $15 and the Griffin Stylus runs $20. You can pick up the Griffin at most Best Buys.

Answer (score 0):

The [Hand stylus](http://handstylus.com/) is another option you can consider. Same size as an average pen, and has a retractable/replaceable nib. What's more, each time the nib is retracted, it's rotated so that you never end up using the same side of the nib twice (in a row).

Though I suppose you could just rotate the entire stylus to get the same effect, it's a thoughtful feature to include.