# What stylus is good for taking notes and writing equation

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app, apple-pencil, stylus

I frequently need to take notes and write equations. I never draw any thing other than graphs, diagrams, etc.. like board works. I am not a painter. I bought an Adobe Ink for my iPad (not iPad pro). Tried to use in one of the Adobe softwares. It looks like that is very good to paint or sketch. But when I try to write some equation, often it jumbles up with subscript notations. It applies its intelligence to turn my `x` into `n`. iPad's own notes app works slightly better. Instead Microsoft Onenote works much better. But still even with onenote things don't work to my expectation. I thought I would be able to take notes straight away. But it is nothing close to that smoothness. If I write very slowly ike painting letters on the board then it somewhat works. Should I change my stylus for a better experience ? Are these styluses `optimized` only for painting ? What budget stylus is good for writing and taking notes ? Or if it is more or less same for all stylus then I would not bother buying another one.

Comment: Related (and closed) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/what-are-the-available-stylus-pens-for-ipad?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that is significantly better than the Adobe Ink, you'll need to go for an iPad Pro with an Apple Pencil. The combination of higher display refresh rates on the iPad Pro and the higher rate of stylus updates from the pen itself - it's really much, much better.

I use the Apple Pencil to write mathematics and draw diagrams/graphs, and it works well for me. However YMMV so be sure to go to a local Apple vendor and try it out before buying.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Pencil is by far the best, best, best option for writing on a screen. It has extremely fast refresh rates, low lag and the friction between the tip and the glass is carefully engineered.

It detects “pressure” and speed and angle of incidence which is much better than almost any other option.

Apple Pencil makes bad apps better and good apps great in my experience. Microsoft, Apple and Astropad / Linea Sketch are the apps I return to time and time again with the pencil. There are dozens of other awesome apps out there, too.